# Can the Grin Technology phaserunner series be used in total headless mode? (No display, POS sensor or torque sensor, bluetooth & throttle only)

Tags: electric-bike, motor

One of my old e-bike has a broken component and is subjected to upgrade, as most of the vendors have either disappeared or declare the component as end-of-lifecycle.

I'm considering Grin PhaseRunner ESC:

https://ebikes.ca/product-info/grin-products/phaserunner.html

and its successor, Grin BaseRunner V4/V5:

https://ebikes.ca/product-info/grin-products/baserunner.html

as the next ESC, it has good customisability & compatibility with many components. But there is one problem: According to its manual, it can only run with a PAS or torque sensor, or both.

Unfortunately the only standard Bottom bracket standard I could use are SRAM GXP or SRAM DUB, none of which has a compatible sensor interface.

So my only option is to use no sensor at all, and rely on  throttle control. I may be able to upgrade to an optical flow based sensor later, which is agnostic to BB standard. Also, Both ESC can communicate with a cell phone with bluetooth, so a display appears to be redundant

So far, this feature has only been seen on Golden Motor xxx Pie series, and obviously, any motor integrated with a hub torque/PAS sensor. I haven't find this option in the manual, or any official build template. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have the knowledge to directly answer your question about running with no pedal sensor.

I can say that when I set up my Grin system, I was able to buy a pedal cadence sensor from them that consisted of a two-part ring of magnets that attached to my inner chainring and a sensor like a bike speedometer that got taped to the bottom bracket shell, and ran that together with a throttle.

(It worked well, but I eventually upgraded to one of their torque-sensing bottom brackets.)

Comment: yeah that's the tricky part: there are 2 PAS sensors: for squared tapered BB and shimano hollowtech BB, there are 1 torque sensor: for squared tapered BB, so oops :-<

Comment: @tribbloid: This is the one I’m thinking of. https://ebikes.ca/shop/electric-bicycle-parts/torque-sensors/pas-12p-chr.html

Comment: I see your point. Unfortunately, "For 74mm 5 Bbolt and 64mm 4 Bolt Cranksets". The most common one is BCD130mm, for fixie it is BCD144mm. In the meantime optical flow sensor has absolute no dependency